# Concatenate string and `\today` macro

Tags: macros, paths, datetime, strings

I'd like to use the `\today` command within a pathname.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[iso]{datetime}   
\graphicspath{{./Figures_\today/}}
```

This should point to `./Figures_2017-11-13/`

What is the best way to concatenate/expand `\today` output with a string?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty of editing your code slightly; feel free to revert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datetime` was replaced by [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2), which allows `\today` to expand. It also uses the ISO format as the default, so just replace

```
\usepackage[iso]{datetime}
```

with

```
\usepackage{datetime2}
```

Comment: I'll defer to you and delete:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your answer is also useful :-) It doesn't have the overhead of loading `datetime2`. (I upvoted it.)

Comment: Thanks -- note that `datetime2` uses a different default time zone than `datetime`

Comment: @bbuzz31 `datetime` doesn't have time zone support. `datetime2` obtains it from `\pdfcreationdate`.